# Visual Basic programming

Tags: vb.net

I am new to the programing world and I am stuck on the below problem please could you assist me

> Write a Visual Basic.net function to calculate the sum of all the numbers in an input field. For example, if the input string is: "ICT2611", then the numbers included in this string are: 2, 6, 1, 1 and their sum is therefore, 2+6+1+1 = 10

Comment: Visual Basic and VBA are really two different things. Updated the tags for you. Please remember it in the future. Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: *"I am new to X"* != Cannot be bothered to try anything yourself.

Comment: Please edit your question and demonstrate, with code, what you have tried and where you are having problems.

Comment: I have moved the contents of the image into a quote block. Please don't use images for anything other than elements that can **only** be portrayed by an image. The use of an image to quote a question you are struggling with gives your post the impression that you are looking for an answer to homework and, since that is not an acceptable use of SO, you are unlikely to get the help you seek. See my other comment for more guidance how to get help with your problem here.

Comment: For starters, you'll need a `For Each` loop to iterate over each character in the string, then inside that, check if the character is a digit.

Comment: What part are you having trouble with?  Getting the value of the input field?  Extracting the digits?  Calculating the sum?  Here's some hints:  1.  Create a console application.  2.  Use `Console.ReadLine` to get the input into a `String` variable.  3.  Use a `For` loop to loop through the characters of the `String`.  4.  Use `Char.IsDigit` to determine if the character is a number.  If it is, then 5.  Add that number to a running total in an `Integer` variable.  6.  Use `Console.WriteLine` to output the result.

Answer (score 0):

The below should solve your problem, it uses Regex to find any matches in the provided string to the expression (numbers 1 - 9), and then iterates through them tallying them up as it goes.

```
Public Function SumOfString(str As String) As Integer
    Dim total As Integer = 0
    For Each i As Match In Regex.Matches(str, "[1-9]")
        total += i.Value
    Next
    Return total
End Function
```

Alternatively the same thing could be achieved like this, this just iterates through each character in the string and then checks to see if it's a digit. If it is a digit then it'll tally it up.

```
Public Function SumOfString(str As String) As Integer
    Dim total As Integer = 0
    For Each i As Char In str
        If Char.IsDigit(i) Then total += Integer.Parse(i)
    Next
    Return total
End Function
```